# "throughout the development program" vs. "throughout the course of the development program"

Tags: phrase-choice

> The same drug substance should be used **throughout the development program**.

Is this okay? I think that this is more appropriate:

> The same drug substance should be used throughout **the course of the development program**.

My intended meaning is: the same drug substance should be used consistently from the first day of the program to the last day. I want to emphasize this "time course" sense. Would sentence 1 manage to convey this "duration & consistency" sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that your first sentence

> The same drug substance should be used throughout the development
>   program.

is more approriate, because **throughout** suffices to convey the meaning of "duration & consistency" as it means during the whole course or period.

Comment: This is interesting. I was positive that "throughout" would not suffice, and posted the question just to make sure. Thank you, Christina